# Can you upload a file to the Slack API using files.upload as a different user?

Tags: slack-api

I'm trying to find a way to have an application post a text snippet to our support channel through the Slack API.  Using the files.upload method, I can create a text snippet and share it with the channel, but the post appears to come from me (because the token used to authenticate the request is mine).

I'm looking for a way to do this, but make it appear with a custom user name and icon, like you can with the chat.postMessage method's username and icon_url parameters.  Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways.

Way 1. - If you only want to upload in a channel and don't need to listen to any conversation, then you can use incoming-webhooks. And then override the username and icon. Read "Customizing your username and icon" in [Here](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks).

Way 2 - You can create a bot user and let the bot user type post this message for you. I guess right now you are using test tokens generated by Slack so you are getting your name only. But if you use bot-user then you can use custom Name and icon_url for your bot.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to customize my username and icon with the incoming-webhooks method.  But I could not find a way to post a **snippet** using this approach.  I tried posting it as preformatted text, but it did not look anywhere near as legible as a text snippet.

Comment: The bot user approach did what I wanted.  It seems like overkill (I'm not using the realtime messaging interface), and it seems odd to me that you can set the user on some methods but not others.  Anyway, problem solved.

Comment: Happy to hear that! Could you also post a new question and answer this yourself (As to how you did this) so that many people also come to know. Great work! @neal

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as @Abhinav Rai suggested, you need have bot. Slack support just answered me the same question.

> To upload files as a bot you'll need to create an associated 'bot user' and post the file using the bot's token: https://api.slack.com/bot-users — all files must be owned by a user account and the bot user will fill this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way 3 which uses the username function from chat.postMessage function. Follow this -

```
import slack
import json
import os

def pureimg(data1):
        data1 = '[{"text": "", "image_url": "'+data1+'"}]'
        data1 = [json.loads(data1[1:-1])]
        return data1

#This function will make the image url to correct format.

slacker = slack.WebClient(token='your-token-here')

payoff=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'filename.png')
#It gives cross OS compatibility on filepath.

response=slacker.files_upload(channel='#theta',file=payoff)
payoff=response['file']['permalink']

#First We upload the local file to Slack and fetch permalink.
#If you do not have any local file just put the external image URL in the payoff.

response=slacker.chat_postMessage(channel='#channel_name', text="Sample Text", username='Bot name', attachments=pureimg(payoff), icon_emoji=':emoji:')

#Then, We post to Slack Channel as a bot!
```