# How to upload file using Slack API as user?

Tags: python, slack-api

Right now, the token used when uploading files via [`files.upload`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) is associated with my Slack user account. So any uploads performed using this token appears to have been made by me.

However, I'd like to specify something like `as_user` (which is available when using [`chat.PostMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage)), which will make the upload appear as if it was uploaded by specified Slack user. Is this possible?

I have this:

```
 upload_file(filepath='/path/to/file.jpg',
             channels='#uploads',
             title='my image',
             initial_comment='pls give me some feedback!')
```

And here's the function being called:

```
import os
import requests

TOKEN = your_token_here

def upload_file(
        filepath,
        channels,
        filename=None,
        content=None,
        title=None,
        initial_comment=None):
    """Upload file to channel

    Note:
        URLs can be constructed from:
        https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload/test
    """

    if filename is None:
        filename = os.path.basename(filepath)

    data = {}
    data['token'] = TOKEN
    data['file'] = filepath
    data['filename'] = filename
    data['channels'] = channels

    if content is not None:
        data['content'] = content

    if title is not None:
        data['title'] = title

    if initial_comment is not None:
        data['initial_comment'] = initial_comment

    filepath = data['file']
    files = {
        'file': (filepath, open(filepath, 'rb'), 'image/jpg', {
            'Expires': '0'
        })
    }
    data['media'] = files
    response = requests.post(
        url='https://slack.com/api/files.upload',
        data=data,
        headers={'Accept': 'application/json'},
        files=files)

    return response.text
```

I did find [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37623776/can-you-upload-a-file-to-the-slack-api-using-files-upload-as-a-different-user), but I don't find the answer clear at all on what could be done to make this work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `as_user` option for uploading and sharing files via API. If you want to upload files to a Slack channel as a different user via [`files.upload`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) you have two options:

1. Create a [bot user](https://api.slack.com/bot-users) and use the access token of that bot user
2. Create a new Slack user for that purpose (e.g. "slackadmin") and use
   the token of that user to upload the file.

You can create bot users through customization or as part of a Slack app.

Comment: How do you get the token of a user (not a bot)? I've been trying to use oauth and it keeps failing. I need to do it from a script.

Comment: There are two ways: 1. Let the user create a [legacy token](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens) and give it to you manually. 2. Let the user install your Slack app via Oauth and collect it programmatically. Method 2 is the recommended one.