# Send Image File to slack using http request sending blank image

Tags: python, python-3.x, slack

I am trying to send a graph to slack channel using Http Request, but I am able to see only a blank png.
If I use the slack WebClient to send the same graph it succeeds but not using an http request.

```
data_anomalies_trend_pd = data_anomalies_trend.toPandas()

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(data_anomalies_trend_pd['date'], data_anomalies_trend_pd['visitors'], marker='o', linestyle='-', color='b')
plt.title('Visitor Trend Over Time')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Visitors')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)  # Rotate x-axis labels for better readability
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
plt.savefig("visitor_trend.png")

with open("visitor_trend.png", "rb") as image_file:
    payload = {
        'channels': channel_id,
        'filetype': 'png',
        'filename': 'visitor_trend.png',
        'title': 'visitor trend'
    }
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {slack_bot_token}'
    }

    response = requests.post(
        url='https://slack.com/api/files.upload',
        data=payload,
        headers=headers,
        files={'file': image_file}
    )
```

I need to use the http request instead of WebClient, since I have reqtrictions on installing slack.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43464873/235698

Comment: @MarkTolonen Difference is the image sent in this case was blank vs the possible duplicate link having pdf. I needed to find a solution to it. Not that I want to know how to send a file to slack

Answer (score 0):

I simply changed to jpg instead of png to have it working.

It seems the WebClient works with png whereas http request works well with jpg for some reason

```
data_anomalies_trend_pd = data_anomalies_trend.toPandas()

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(data_anomalies_trend_pd['date'], data_anomalies_trend_pd['visitors'], marker='o', linestyle='-', color='b')
plt.title('Visitor Trend Over Time')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Visitors')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)  # Rotate x-axis labels for better readability
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
plt.savefig("visitor_trend.jpg")

with open("visitor_trend.jpg", "rb") as image_file:
    payload = {
        'channels': channel_id,
        'filetype': 'jpg',
        'filename': 'visitor_trend.jpg',
        'title': 'visitor trend'
    }
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {slack_bot_token}'
    }

    response = requests.post(
        url='https://slack.com/api/files.upload',
        data=payload,
        headers=headers,
        files={'file': image_file}
    )
```